# UIDocumentInteractionController Opening file in a specific app without options

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, handler, uidocumentinteraction

I'm using UIDocumentInteractionController to open a file in another app, DropBox.

What i'm trying to do is open the file in another specific app , but i only managed so far to display the supported apps and allowing the user to choose.

```cpp
UIDocumentInteractionController *udi = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: jpgPath]];
[udi retain];
CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
[udi presentOpenInMenuFromRect:r inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

This presents a list of apps supported, but i want to directly open the file with dropbox, without the options box. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be delighted to be contradicted, but I think this is not possible (at least up to and including iOS 4).

The normal way to open a file in another application is to use a Custom URL scheme. (See the documentation for openURL: in the UIApplication Class Reference and also [Implementing Custom URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html%22Implementing%20Custom%20URL%20schemes%22) in the iOS Application Programming Guide.) To the best of my knowledge, Dropbox have not implemented a Custom URL Scheme. And, given that, this approach is closed.

UIDocumentationController is pretty opaque. You can coax it into [telling you whether or not there is any application on the device that will open your file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233837/how-to-tell-programmatically-if-there-are-are-not-any-registered-apps-that-su). But it's not clear you can do much else.

Comment: And if we're talking about instagram? it has the instagram:// scheme but i don't know of any normal way to pass an image there.

Comment: Has iOS 5 perhaps added anything for us?  I can't find anything, but thought I'd ask in case someone has!!