# Opening external app to view the local file in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am developing an iOS app and would like to open the locally stored file using external app. I know that typically it can be done through "Open with..." menu, but instead previewing it locally and giving Open with menu, I'd like to open it instantly with an another app.

For instance, I have a Help file in PDF format, which I'd like to open at once when user clicks [?] button. I want it to open using specifically Adobe Acrobat. No problem if it is not installed :)

Any ideas?

Comment: Not supported yet it seems:
[similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539243/openurl-a-local-file-or-force-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-to-use-a-specific?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

well usually you don't need to open a fairly common format with outside apps...you can do it inside your app using stuff Apple provides in frameworks .

For example pdf can be opened with WebKit or with [Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101).

In your situation just push a UIView with the pdf open with CoreGraphics...it shouldn't take more than 2 min to set up.

Comment: I know about core graphics. But lets admit it: Apple's support of PDF format is way less feature full than Adobe's. Besides that is not what am asking :)

Comment: got a solution for this yet? I also need to do the same thing without going through the openIn menu.