# Add 'Open With' to own app

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, share

I am currently developing an app that has to be able to share documents between two apps. A PDF file will be openend in my app and has to be sent to another app, Pages for example, to make changes to it. From there I can send the file back to my own app if the second app supports it. Now I have been able to register the file types for my own app, and it is showing up and opening files from the second app.

The problem I'm having is adding an 'Open with' option to my own app. Apple's documentation only seems to cover assigning file types to your own app, but not how to share files with other apps. Can any of you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UIDocumentInteractionController` explained [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1) and maybe this link will help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957980/how-to-check-if-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-will-fail-to-open-document-due-to) too.